# Ghostscript problem

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, dvi

I'm trying to submit a LaTeX paper to [Wiley ISMRW](http://www.wiley.com/bw/submit.asp?ref=0740-3194) but get the following error:

```
************************************************************************

command: dvipdf MRM3.dvi
Command Ok
dvips: warning: no config file for `generic'

Error: /undefinedresource in --findresource--

Operand stack:

   DefaultColorRendering   ColorRendering   DefaultColorRendering

Execution stack:

   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   14   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--

Dictionary stack:

   --dict:1069/1417(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:89/200(L)--   --dict:135/300(L)--   --dict:43/200(L)--   --dict:57/75(L)--   --dict:212/315(L)--   --dict:72/107(L)--   --dict:0/10(G)--   --dict:0/10(L)--   --dict:0/50(G)--   --dict:56/71(L)--   --dict:212/315(L)--   --dict:2/2(L)--   --dict:16/18(ro)(G)--

Current allocation mode is local

Last OS error: 2

ESP Ghostscript 7.07.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

dvips: Problems with file writing; probably disk full.

************************************************************************
```

I read about patch fixes etc. for these kinds of problems, however this is an on-line submission, so I can't really update their Ghostscript etc. :s

Comment: By MRM, do you mean [Wiley ISMRM](http://www.wiley.com/bw/submit.asp?ref=0740-3194)?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question got migrated here from a different stackexchange site. Please also register yourself on this site and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem,

it was due to an unknown font in an eps file. I embedded the font in the image and the error was no more.

Comment: Indeed, missing fonts in embedded vector images are a source of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem and I used following command to embed the fonts with GhostScript

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=output.eps input.eps
```